# Azure DevOps Tests Run Successfully on RELEASE, Runs Indefinitely on DEBUG

Tags: c#, azure-devops, automapper, autofac, mstest

I am using Autofac and Automapper in my solution.  I have a unit test written and it runs without any issues locally.  When I created the pull request, the unit tests run successfully in RELEASE; however, in DEBUG, it runs indefinitely and after some time (i.e., 45 minutes), it just fails.

I tried adjusting my code in such a way that it will just use the `container` and not the `scope` from Autofac to resolve some dependencies.  I am trying to test the resolution of my application and also the `AssertConfigurationIsValid` of my mapper profiles; but still the issue persists.

```
        public static IContainer Configure()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            //Application
            builder.RegisterType<DerivedBatchVolumesApplication>().AsSelf();

            //Features
            builder.RegisterType<QEndOfMonthCalculator>().As<IQEndOfMonthCalculator>();
            builder.RegisterType<QProgressiveRounder>().As<IQProgressiveRounder>();

            //Configuration
            builder.Register(x => QEndOfMonthCalculatorConfiguration.FromMetadata()).As<IQEndOfMonthCalculatorConfiguration>();
            builder.Register(x => QDerivedBatchVolumesConfiguration.FromMetadata()).As<IQDerivedBatchVolumesConfiguration>();

            //Data
            builder.RegisterType<QTranTicketRepository>().As<IQRepository<TranTicketDO>>();
            builder.RegisterType<QCtBatchRepository>().As<IQRepository<CtBatchDO>>();
            builder.RegisterType<QPaystationRepository>().As<IQRepository<PaystationDO>>();
            builder.RegisterType<QTicketVolRepository>().As<IQRepository<TicketVolDO>>();
            builder.RegisterType<QSctrlRelatedCtrRepository>().As<IQRepository<SctrlRelatedCtrDO>>();
            builder.RegisterType<QAllocVolRepository>().As<IQRepository<AllocVolDO>>();

            //Mapper
            builder.RegisterType<QMapper>().As<IQMapper>();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
                .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<InjectableAttribute>() != null)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();

            //Data Access
            builder.RegisterType<TranTicket>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<CtBatch>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<Paystation>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<TicketVol>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<SctrlRelatedCtr>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<AllocVol>().AsSelf();

            return builder.Build();
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var container = ContainerConfiguration.Configure();
            _scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
            _mapper = _scope.Resolve<IQMapper>();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            _scope.Dispose();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void MapperConfigurations_AreValid()
        {
            _mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _endOfMonthCalculator = new Mock<IQEndOfMonthCalculator>();
            _tranTicket = new Mock<IQRepository<TranTicketDO>>();
            _ctBatch = new Mock<IQRepository<CtBatchDO>>();
            _paystation = new Mock<IQRepository<PaystationDO>>();
            _ticketVol = new Mock<IQRepository<TicketVolDO>>();
            _sctrlRelatedCtr = new Mock<IQRepository<SctrlRelatedCtrDO>>();
            _allocVol = new Mock<IQRepository<AllocVolDO>>();
            _derBatchVolConfiguration = new Mock<IQDerivedBatchVolumesConfiguration>();

            _container = ContainerConfiguration.Configure();
            _progressiveRounder = _container.Resolve<IQProgressiveRounder>();
            _mapper = _container.Resolve<IQMapper>();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            _container.Dispose();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void DerivedBatchVolumesApplication_Resolves()
        {
            //Arrange & Act
            var application = _container.Resolve<DerivedBatchVolumesApplication>();

            //Assert
            application.ShouldNotBeNull();
            application.ShouldBeOfType<DerivedBatchVolumesApplication>();
        }
```

My expectation is that the unit test will run successfully for the DEBUG like how it is for the RELEASE.

Comment: does it works locally ? do you have any stack trace on where the test is stuck ?

Comment: Yes, it does work locally and even on the build server, but only for the RELEASE build.  It does not generate any stack trace, but when it starts to hit the unit test which uses the dependency builder module, it just gets stuck there.

Comment: could you add some traces to try locate where it get stuck ?